# Can't find WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I installed MobileFirst Server 6.3  for production on Windows. As aplication server I'm using  WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile. I can not find WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console. Does this console exist for Liberty Profile?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst is not related at all here. It's just a web app deployed to the application server.

Unlike WebSphere Full profile, WebShere Liberty profile does not come with a UI console.

Comment: Actually you can add simple console to the Liberty - [Admin Center](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0), however it is not related to the Integrated Solutions Console from full WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: Thank you Idan for your response. I need to do LTPA-based authentication in my app.  As I understood  I need  to install WebSphere Full profile to be able to configure  LTPA  on application server yes?

Comment: @Madiyor Did you try searching for "liberty ltpa"?  These look relevant: Configuring LTPA on the Liberty profile http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ltpa.html and Customizing SSO configuration using LTPA cookies for the Liberty profile http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_sso.html

Comment: No I did not, Bkail. Thank you